# Why does footer tag moves out of p tag?

Tags: html

In this [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/dkjain/r5z135gf/1/), the `<footer>` tag moves out of `<p>` tag when rendered, even though in the HTML it's placed inside the `<p>` tag.

Can anybuddy explain this behavior?

**HTML**

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus voluptatum tenetur sunt cumque quod non, excepturi, pariatur qui dolorem ipsum, nesciunt veniam ab! Quos vero perferendis, consequuntur modi, doloremque tempore!
<footer>Some footer </footer>
```

**CSS**

```
p{border: 1px solid  #000;}
footer{border: 2px solid green;}
```

Comment: Does it also happen when footer is replaced by a div?

Comment: the </p> should be after the word tempore!  the footer is it's own <div> https://jsfiddle.net/caj308yh/

Comment: mm759, yes it also happens with `div`. But in my opinion, browsers should not change the actual html. Why do browser's do that? Is if specified in the specs?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple.

`<footer>` tag is not allowed inside `<p>`, `<span>` tag etc. Just like `<p>` tag not allowed inside `<span>`.

But you can use `<p>` inside `<footer>`.

`<footer>` itself is an independent section (It has a semantic to tell the browser that the section is the footer of the `html` page and has a display block).

Comment: @Dan Off the top of my head, I believe he is correct. A `<p>` element can only contain phrasing content and a footer's nearest ancestor must be a sectioning element. The validator gives an error if you put `<footer>` inside a `<p>`.

Comment: Syam, I agree that it's invalid html. FYI, I tried putting `<p>` inside `<span>` and checked out the source in Chrome. Unlike `<footer>` inside `<p>`, chrome did not move `<p>` out of `<span>`.

Answer (score 0):

replace the `<p>` tag with `<div>`

Answer (score -1):

Dyana Putry, did not answer the question however when I tried what she suggested,  it did make things clear as to why such behavior. Also, Rob (another comm enter) notes that a `<p>` element can only contain phrasing content and a footer's nearest ancestor must be a sectioning element.

This makes me conclude that it entirely depends on the parent element type. `<p>`, a phrasing context element cannot have any sectioning context element. while `<div>` a general element can be used in any context, therefore browsers doesn't mind a `<footer>`, sectioning element inside `<div>`.

Comment: It's not really that simple. For example, a `<pre>` element has the same content model as a `<p>` element, and so  a `<footer>` inside a `<pre>` is just as invalid as a `<footer>` inside a `<p>`. But if you replace the `<p>` with a `<pre>` you'll notice that the `<pre>` element contains the `<footer>` just fine. In fact. it's just the rules of the HTML parser, which causes the `<footer>` start tag to close an open `<p>` element, but does not have an equivalent rule for open `<pre>` elements.

Comment: hmm...interesting. Thanks for your input.